# Unfound train_station / bus_station in Google Places

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm working on a software using Google Maps Javascript API, with Google Places, and I'd like to get a lot of places near a locality, including train stations. Everything works well : I find stores, restaurants, doctors, etc. But, when it comes to train stations, it's a bit random : for some cities, Google returns me results, but for (a lot of) other cities, I receive a ZERO_RESULT, even when I know that there is a train station near my location.

Here is an exemple :

```
var latlng = {'lat': 43.679188, 'lng': 4.132562}
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(myMap);
service.nearbySearch({
    location: latlng,
    radius: 5000,
    type:'train_station'
}, callback);
```

There is a train station near this place, and Google knows it, since it is displayed on the map : 
https://www.google.com/maps?ll=43.679188,4.132562&z=18&t=m&hl=fr&gl=US&mapclient=apiv3&cid=9554763916834935204

So, how can I get that train station ? Are there other types which design such places (I tried 'subway_station', 'transit_station', 'taxi_stand', 'bus_station', and my question is valid for all those types too) ? Or am I missing something ?

Comment: I can't confirm if Google Maps data are different (slightly) with Google Places data. What you can see (based on the map you provided) may be maps-specific. If you want, you can [Add Places](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place#add-place-overview) using the Places API. However, it will still undergo moderation process before it will be available for other searches (Text, Radar)

Comment: Thank you, I will try to add the places I want and the places our customers want using this ! That's kind of bad however that Google Places doesn't use Google Maps data for places like this...